# Remove Mandrill footer

Tags: mandrill, unsubscribe

I'm sending emails using the Mandrill API, Is there any way to remove their footer or edit it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFD76.png)

as I wanted to use my unsubscribe url instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn it off by their settings ! as the following image :

[image]